# Footer/vspace rendering differently after TeX Live version update (2019 to 2022)

Tags: spacing, texlive, texlive2022, texlive-2023

I am encountering unexpected rendering changes in my PDF output after upgrading from an older version of pdfTeX. Previously, I was using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)`, and now I'm using `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)`.

The issue manifests in my footers, which consist of two red lines. Since the update, these lines have shifted downwards, and the "Page X of Y" footer text has moved up slightly, despite no changes to the LaTeX code.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Similar issues were reported ([one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684586/spacing-issues-between-latex-versions), [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600349/newest-tex-live-updates-introduce-vertical-space-above-varwidth), [three](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/586)). However, none of the suggested solutions seem to resolve my problem.

I have also tested on Overleaf and found the issue is present with pdfTeX versions starting from 2022 (versions before and including 2021 (legacy) render the PDFs correctly).

How can I get my PDFs to generate like they used to?

Here's an example of my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[top=3.2cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, foot=1.7cm, head=2.6cm, heightrounded, portrait, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand\FooterRedLine{\vspace*{-6.8mm}\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.5\textwidth-1.2cm}{2pt}}}

\newcommand{\SetupHeaderAndFooter}{
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.2pt}
    
    \fancyfoot[L]{
      \FooterRedLine \hfill \FooterRedLine
    }
    \fancyfoot[C]{
      \includegraphics[width=2.2cm, keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a} \\
      \small{ABC\texttrademark} \\[1mm]
      \scriptsize{\textit{ABC}}
    }
    \fancyfoot[R]{
      \vspace{3mm}
      \small{Page X of Y}
    }
  }
  
}


\SetupHeaderAndFooter
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

It seems changing vspace has no effect

- `\FooterRedLine`: removing the `\vspace` did nothing.
- `Page X of Y` footer text: changing the vspace to `\vspace*{3mm}`, `\vspace{30mm}`, or `\vspace*{30mm}`, did nothing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: hm, fancyhdr changed its code, it now starts the footnote boxes with `\raggedright\leavevmode\ignorespaces` which means you are already in hmode and then \vspace doesn't do what you expect. You can try `\par\vspace{3mm}... ` and `\par \vspace{-XX}\includegraphics`  with suitable values.

Comment: note also `\small` does not take an argument, the braces are doing nothing in ` \small{Page X of Y}`